# Stream Writer File Size

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter, .net

Does anyone have an idea as to why the text files I am creating in VB are only 4kb? I am trying to parse HTML and I created a structure to store all of the info. I just want to save the info in a text file so I can look at it easier.

The file is being cut off mid stream @ 4096 bytes. I know the blocks are in 4kb increments, but I dont know why it would not give me all of the data I want.

Here is how I create my streamwriter:

```
Shared objWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
objWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\jmcgowan\Desktop\DNSReports" & newArgs & "DNS.txt", False)
```

I then use a objwriter.writeLine call to write to the file. I have checked that all of the information is being gathered, so that is not the issue. Just looking to see if anyone has any idea how I can get this to work!

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem! The StreamWriter class in vb.net automatically creates the file, but only with 4096 bytes of memory. In order to expand the size of the file, I did this to the declaration

```
    objWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, False, Encoding.Unicode, 8192)
```

By adding the unicode encoding (must be done to give buffer size) and the integer (the number of bytes to be allocated), you can have a much bigger file.

Comment: Considering that Unicode is not an actual encoding at all, I wonder just what this does, or is expected to do. An encoding would be something like UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32, UTF-32BE, or UTF-32LE.

Comment: I used unicode solely because I only wanted the raw text. You could use any other type of encoding, but since I just needed a placeholder there, I chose to use unicode!

Comment: But that is just the point: “Unicode” is **not an encoding**.

Comment: Oh, sorry I must've misunderstood you. Yeah, im not sure how it works. It was an option, so I chose it and it worked for what I needed it to!

Comment: Perhaps you have forgotten to call `objWriter.Close()` and `objWrite.Dispose()`?

Comment: I second @AndrewMorton's opinion - wrap your writer into a `Using` block. Then you don't need these hacks.

Comment: According to [this ASP.NET forum link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1071936.aspx?Strange+Unexpected+end+of+file+while+parsing+Name+has+occurred) a StreamWriter has a default size of 4K (and doesn't dynamically increase). I was glad to find this stackoverflow post detailing a way to increase the size.